# Integer matrices with determinant equal to $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Integer matrices with determinant equal to $1$ are quite useful in many situations. Take, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358082/generate-integer-matrices-with-integer-eigenvalues). For the $2 \times 2$ case it's easy to find many such matrices, e.g.,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
3 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
5 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

- But how to construct the procedure for generation integer matrix with
  arbitrarily chosen dimension $n \times n$?
- Is it a method which is as general as it is possible?
- I'm also interested in the answer how many degrees of freedom has an
  integer matrix with determinant equal 1 (or other perhaps number) ?
  Without determinant constraint $n \times n$ matrix has of course $n^2$ degrees of freedom.. how many is lost when we constrain it with determinant?

Comment: There is a name for these, the special linear group of $n\times n$ matrices over the integers, $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, a group with respect to matrix multiplication.

Comment: @hardmath is this somewhere described? all references are valuable..

Comment: This [1992 paper in the Proc. of the AMS](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-115-01/S0002-9939-1992-1079696-5/S0002-9939-1992-1079696-5.pdf) opens by describing one set of generators called *transvections* $T_{ij}$.  To obtain a *presentation* of these finitely generated groups, one needs to articulate the *relations* satisfied by those generators, which is the topic of that paper.

Comment: @hardmath paper maybe a little too advanced as for me but anyway thank you very much..

Comment: I'll try my hand at writing up an exposition of this material for you, esp. as it bears on your interest in the "degrees of freedom" issue.

Comment: @hardmath I would be very grateful for such exposition. I love to learn something really new for me.. I should mention only  that I will be again  logged on Monday, so then I will be able to see the material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just start with the identity matrix and apply transformations that don't change the determinant:

1. Adding to column (row) another column (row) multiplied by an integer.
2. Performing an [even permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of the columns (rows).

Hart to tell what is degrees of freedom for a discrete set. Its dimension is zero.
But you can think of it a cutting all the $n^2$ dimensions that you had by one equation. So, $n^2-1$.

Comment: Give some examples how this acts... what about degrees of freedom ?

Comment: Could you obtain with this procedure for example $\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
3 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @Widawensen I would have to try. But for $2\times2$ matrices you can get all of them by mutiplying together powers of the two matrices $[[1,1],[0,1]]$ and $[[0,-1],[1,0]]$.

Comment: That's the other method (maybe to add to the answer?)  it is really quite general - multiplying matrices with determinant $1$ gives really always matrix with determinant $1$ ..

Comment: For the claim that these generate all the $2\times 2$ cases, see [this previous Question, "Generating the special linear group of 2 by 2 matrices over the integers"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927879/generating-the-special-linear-group-of-2-by-2-matrices-over-the-integers).

Comment: To say truth the best method  could be such that  would allow to generate these matrices in some kind of order, for example to cover them all in vicinity of some other reference matrix ( for example $I$) to make all their set as "dense" as possible - I'm not sure whether only adding multiplied columns is enough systematic for this aim, maybe it would be worth to add some additional strategy to this procedure..

Comment: @hardmath thank you for valuable link ..

Answer (score 4):

To motivate what might be said about "degrees of freedom" in the more general $n\times n$ case, let's look at the $2\times 2$ case in some detail.

One might informally say that the *degrees of freedom* in the [special linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group) $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has an intuitive sense of "the number of coordinates needed to specify an instance".

This is a firmer notion when the coordinates involved are *real numbers* than when, as here, the coordinates are only discrete integers.  The problem is related to the possibility that a pair of integers might be coded together as a single integer, so that the counting "how many coordinates are needed" becomes muddled.  In the case of real numbers we are saved by imposing a requirement that any "coding" has to involve continuous functions (in a suitably restricted domain) that are continuously invertible (decoding).  This prevents a pair of real numbers from being combined into a single real number.

Acknowledging that we are walking on slippery ground, let's consider a couple of "natural ways" to parameterize $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.  The first involves making an arbitrary choice of the two diagonal entries $a,d$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} $$

Since we desire that $ad - bc = 1$, we have (in order to get an element of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$) only to solve:

$$ bc = ad - 1 $$

Apart from the peculiar case that $ad = 1$ (which admits an infinite number of solutions $b,c$ provided at least one of them is zero), we find that there will be only finitely many $b,c$ which "factor" $ad - 1$.

This seems to say that there are (loosely speaking) two degree of freedom, since (with the two exceptions $a = d = \pm 1$) the values $a,d$ can be chosen arbitrarily and leave a finite number of additional "choices" (about the ways $ad - 1$ will factor).

On the other hand we might begin with choosing $a$ and $b$.  Now the valid choices are those pairs $a,b$ which are coprime (no common divisor greater than one).  Although not every pair is satisfactory in this sense, [the relative fraction of coprime pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime) $a,b$ in an expanding region $[-M,M]\times [-M,M]$ as $M\to \infty$ converges to $6/\pi^2$, which is roughly $61\%$.

So again it seems that choosing $a,b$ requires two degrees of freedom.  Further, as $a,b$ are coprime, there exist coefficients $c,d$ such that $ad-bc=1$.  Then we can introduce an additional integer coordinate $k$ because:

$$ \det \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c+ak & d+bk \end{bmatrix} = 1 $$

By this reckoning we would have three degrees of freedom at our disposal!

Comment: Very interesting argumentation, integer entries can lead to paradoxes?

Comment: Well, it reinforces @user463383's remark that it's "har[d] to tell" what degrees of freedom are for a discrete set.  I don't think the results are really paradoxical.  The first way gives two degrees as a lower bound (because we neglect that the number of factorizations is finite for each $a,d$ but on average grows as $a,,d$ become larger), and the second way is an upper bound (because we award two degrees of freedom for $a,b$).

Comment: O.k. Let some kind of ambiguity remain.. maybe the nature of variety ( I'm not sure whether the word "variety" is proper here, maybe manifold?) can be  generated by the determinant equation ( this would be some kind of the grid lying on this hyper-surface in 4D)

Answer (score 2):

Say that we want to generate the integer matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\dots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\dots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$
so that $\det(A)=1$. We start by randomizing the rows $2,\dots, n$. Now a cofactor expansion in row 1 shows that the problem is equivalent to the one of finding solutions to the diophantine equation
$$c_{11}a_{11}+c_{12}a_{12}+\dots+c_{1n}a_{1n} = 1$$
where $c_{11},\dots,c_{1n}$ are the cofactors of the first row of $A$. Since the rows $2,\dots,n$ have been set, the cofactors can easily be calculated. The diophantine equation is solvable if $\gcd\{c_{11},\dots,c_{1n}\}=1$ and in that case the solutions depend on $n-1$ parameters. An advantage of this method is that you can control the size of the entries of $A$.

I have developed a Python program that randomizes an integer matrix with determinant as a parameter. You can find it here: https://github.com/andis854/matrix_rdn_det.

Comment: Interesting method but how  .... we can be sure  that $\gcd\{c_{11},\dots,c_{1n}\}=1$ ?

Comment: We cannot! So in that case one has to generate new numbers for the rows $2,\dots,n$. However the likelihood of the $\gcd$ not being $1$ is low, so this is not a serious computational problem.