# How to extend the matrix with determinant 1 to keep it

Tags: matrices, number-theory, determinant, diophantine-equations

Lets consider 2x2 integer matrix with determinant equal 1:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I am working on the following:

How to extend this to 3x3 matrix in order to get another matrix with determinant 1:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & e \\
 c & d & f \\
 i & h & g \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

And also is there any $a,b,c,d$ for which this extension is unique.
I even have no idea how to start solving this. 
I have discovered the following so far on the web, but not sure how to use this:

[Integer matrices with determinant equal to $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358484/integer-matrices-with-determinant-equal-to-1)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24131/is-the-semigroup-of-nonnegative-integer-matrices-with-determinant-1-finitely-gen

EDITED:

Actually I am looking for general algorithm, how to construct **all** 3x3 matricies from 2x2 matrix with determinant 1.

EDITED 2:

Some samples of such matricies:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 5 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -6 & -5 & -4 \\
 9 & 5 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Well surely $$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

You can just set $g = 1$ and $e,f,i,h = 0$:

$$1 = \begin{vmatrix}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & 0\\
 c & d & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

Furthermore, the extension is never unique since:

$$1 = \begin{vmatrix}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & 0\\
 c & d & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & 0\\
 c & d & 0\\
 a & b & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$

Note that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be $0$, so the two extensions are indeed different.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am just wondering if there is any known algorithm of constructing such 3x3 matricies from the 2x2? And not sure if understand the part of uniqueness, could you please detalize abit?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan Concerning uniqueness, the determinant is invariant under elementary row operations. So 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & 0\\
 c & d & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & 0\\
 c & d & 0\\
 a & b & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$
because the second matrix is obtained from the first by adding the first row to the third. Furthermore, these two matrices are not the same since $a$ and $b$ cannot both be $0$. If they were, then we would have:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
 0 & 0 \\
 c & d \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0 \ne 1$$

Comment: You can in general construct such $3\times 3$ extensions by applying elementary row and column operations on the example above.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but could you please describe the idea on the following matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan By adding the first row multiplied by $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the third, and adding the second row multiplied by $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the third we obtain:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\  -1 & 0 & 1 \\  -1 & 0 & 2
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-1+n-m & n & 2+n+m
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: By further adding the first column multiplied by $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the third column, and adding the second column multiplied by $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the third, we obtain:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-1+n-m & n & 2+n+m
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1+k+l \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1-k \\ 
-1+n-m & n & 2+n+m-k(-1+n+m)+ln
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Also, you could first do the column operations, and then the row ones:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\  -1 & 0 & 1 \\  -1 & 0 & 2
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1+k+l \\
  -1 & 0 & 1-k \\
  -1 & 0 & 2-k
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1+k+l \\
  -1 & 0 & 1-k \\
  -1+n-m & n & m(1+k+l)+n(1-k) + 2-k
\end{vmatrix}$$
I hope you get the general idea.

Comment: Yes the idea behind the uniqueness is clear thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$SL_2 \mathbb Z$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta
\end{array}
\right)
$$

homomorphic image

$SL_3 \mathbb Z$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha^2 & 2 \alpha \beta &  \beta ^2\\
\alpha \gamma & \alpha \delta + \beta \gamma & \beta \delta\\
\gamma^2    & 2 \gamma \delta  & \delta^2
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

If you take the transpose of the 3 by 3, you get an anti-homomorphism.

Comment: This is exactly what was looking for. Could you please provide some reference regarding to this result?

Comment: And also is it possible extend this on nxn matrix?

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan  the earliest version I have is a book by Fricke and Klein (1897) https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false

Comment: But this is still not exactly what I wanted, sorry and the problem is that I am looking for extension, while we have $\alpha^2$ and $2\alpha \beta$ while there should be $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Thank you for the book.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider a block-diagonal matrix, for which the first diagonal block is $\;\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}$.